# How to add text with subtitle in select box

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectbox

Is it possible to add title and sub title in a select box

```
<select name="sel_location_type" id="sel_location_type">
  <option value="1">Factory/Warehouse <span class="subtitle">subtitle1</span></option>
  <option value="2" selected>Residential <span class="subtitle">subtitle2</span></option>
  <option value="3">Business (with loading dock) <span class="subtitle">subtitle3</span></option>
  <option value="4">Business (needs liftgate) <span class="subtitle">subtitle4</span></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Where you want to add title in select box...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes it is easily possible using bootstrap select library. See [docs](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#customize-options)**

You can use it by adding the below css and js CDNs in your webpage, :

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<!-- (Optional) Latest compiled and minified JavaScript translation files -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>
```

Once the CDN is added, your HTML will look like:

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-size="5">
  <option data-subtext="Heinz">Ketchup</option>
</select>
```

Beneath your HTML you have to have to define the `selectpicker` initialization JS function like:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
  showSubtext:true
});
```

Comment: I am actually preparing a fiddle for it ... it got some error.

Comment: @Renjitha I don't fully understand, what you mean by not selectable ?

Comment: I don't this is possible by any easy means since the subtext is inside the selectable option. However, if you can work with a subtext being a header above the underlying options you can try [optgroups](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#select-boxes-with-optgroups)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18527351)

Comment: @Sid You're that does make sense.. Thanks I'll edit this answer to include more info.

Comment: @DaniyalNasir <option data-subtext="subtitle1"></option> selction is enabled for this section, no need to select the subtext section.

Comment: What I understand that you don't want the option to be selected when the subtext of the option is clicked. If that is what you're looking for, this is not currently supported by library. You have to create a workaround for that.